# Lazy scrolling with silvers

Tags: flutter

I want lazy scrolling when my all page is scrolled so i have to use Custom Scroll View.
now CustomScrollView can have just silvers children, my problem is have many lists and widgets,
expanded widget that has his own list.
to achieve the best lazy scrolling i have to some how get to top level widget all my lists and that can become very nasty.
LeagueGamesList widget contain list of expanded widgets that every expanded widget is a list.
how i can do it and still keep order and maintain widgets?

```
   SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      if (_highlights.length > 0)
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'Highlights',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                                      ),
                                      Image.asset(
                                        AppIcons.rightArrow,
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        width: 20,
                                        height: 20,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: HighlightRow(highlights: _highlights),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      Visibility(
                        visible: _advertisements.length != 0,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                          child: HomepageBanner(
                            advertisement: _homepageAdvertisement,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      if (Provider.of<ArticlesProvider>(context).get().length > 0)
                        HomepageArticles(
                          articles: Provider.of<ArticlesProvider>(context).get(),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }, childCount: 1),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Visibility(
                      visible: isLoading,
                      child: SpinKitFadingCircle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 20,
                      ),
                      replacement: SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ),
                    DateButton(
                      dateString: getDateString(),
                      dayForwards: dayForwards,
                      dayBackwards: dayBackwards,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                  ],
                );
              }, childCount: 1),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
                print(index);
                return LeagueGamesList(
                  leagueFixture: leagueFixtures[index],
                  closeExpanders: false,
                  openExpanders: isDateChanged,
                  rowHeight: rowHeight,
                );
              }, childCount: leagueFixtures.length),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

my expanded container that will contain a list

```
class ExpandableContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool expanded;
  final double collapsedHeight;
  final double expandedHeight;
  final Widget child;

  ExpandableContainer({
    @required this.child,
    this.collapsedHeight = 0.0,
    this.expandedHeight = 0,
    this.expanded = true,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return new AnimatedContainer(
      duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      width: screenWidth,
      height: expanded ? expandedHeight : collapsedHeight,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: child,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting lists in lists make only the deepest list be actual `SliverList`s and combine them together using `MultiSliver`s from my package [sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools)

Comment: i cant do it i have couple of lists and widgets not in the list i have to contain all of that under single scrollable page

Comment: Sorry misread the code, I updated my answer

Comment: ty i will give it a try, is it can deal with expanded lists? now my builder build 2 expanded lists instead of 16 when i print the index

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `expanded list`?

Comment: animated container that when is clicked opened and contain a list, i added my expanded container, when i scroll it is opened on start and i give the opportunity to close that so it can be really tricky to lazy scroll this

Comment: Ah well no because that’s not a sliver, but I do have `SliverAnimatedPaintExtent` in my package as well that can at least animate height changes although that will probably not satisfy your needs completely.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue on github with a feature request, but if you really need this asap then you’ll have to dive into writing a custom sliver

Comment: ty i think I'm not control enough flutter to implement such a thing, i also don't understand why everything must be a silver you saw how i did silver list of 1 length to put my not list widgets is it really the right implementation?

Comment: That’s simply the only way to get these kinds of nested structures to lazy load properly. Now your whole nested list will load at once and scrolling will also behave strangely.